# How to fetch a set of data sorted by a field but the null values should come later & sorted by different criteria?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have the following table structure:

Table:

1. Column 1: pid (Integer, Primary Key, Auto Increment, NOT NULL )
2. Column 2: name (Varchar, NOT NULL )
3. Column 3: balance (Int(11) )

Column 3 (balance) can have NULL values.

I want to write a query to get the all entries sorted by **balance** (both in `ASC` & `DESC` order), but the entries with NULL values should come after the sorted list and they should be sorted by **name**.

For example, for the following data:

```
|--------pid--------|--------name--------|--------balance--------

          1         |        Tom         |      1000000000
          2         |        Jerry       |      NULL
          3         |        Spike       |      4000000000
          4         |        Butch       |      NULL
          5         |        Nibbles     |      NULL
          6         |        Tyke        |      3000000000
```

the expected result is (For ascending order):

```
|--------pid--------|--------name--------|--------balance--------

          1         |        Tom         |      1000000000
          6         |        Tyke        |      3000000000
          3         |        Spike       |      4000000000
          4         |        Butch       |      NULL
          2         |        Jerry       |      NULL
          5         |        Nibbles     |      NULL
```

What should be  the query for this case?

Comment: What has this to do with the `git` tag?

Comment: @RaulRene: Apologies, git tag got saved from a previous unasked question

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY (IF(`balance` IS NULL, `name`, `balance`))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY ISNULL(balance), IFNULL(balance, name);
```

It will first sort by ISNULL (so non-null balances will be first), and then sort by "name", if the "balance" is null, or sort by "balance" otherwise.

You can of course add DESC or ASC after the ISNULL() or IFNULL() expressions. You can control whether you want null values first:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY ISNULL(balance) DESC, IFNULL(balance, name) ASC;
```

or null values last:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY ISNULL(balance) ASC, IFNULL(balance, name) ASC;
```

Explanation of IFNULL can be found [here](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/control-flow-functions/if-null-function.php) and explanation of ISNULL is [here](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/is-null%28%29.php).

Comment: how do I add the ascending & descending Criteria

Comment: For example that should work: SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY ISNULL(balance) ASC, IFNULL(balance, name) DESC;

Comment: and what about in mysql?

Comment: What do you mean? This query is actually MySQL only - there is no IF, ISNULL or IFNULL in ANSI SQL, though there are more general approaches, like COALESCE or CASE.